# Question on monotonicity and differentiability

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \Re$ be continuous. Assume $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere and $f(0)>f(1)$.

Does this imply that there exists an $x\in(0,1)$ such that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and $f'(x)<0$?

My gut feeling is yes but I do not see a way to prove it. Any thoughts (proof/counterexample)?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you taken inventory of the continuous, a.e. differentiable functions you've encountered...? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) satisfies your hypotheses (up to sign) but the derivative vanishes whenever the function is differentiable.

Comment: Take the Cantor function and subtract $\frac12 x$ for an example where the derivative is *negative* and defined almost everywhere, yet $f(1) > f(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in another answer the Cantor function is a counterexample.
You would need to assume differentiability for all $x \in (0,1)$. "Almost everywhere" is not good enough.